# Eclipse vanishes with no warning while building

Tags: eclipse, ant

This does not always happen, but sometimes when I try to build a (large) project with ant, Eclipse simply vanishes.

I can relaunch eclipse, but will not be able to find any useful information in the error view except "The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes." upon workspace restart.

Has anyone experienced this or could provide some insight on what could be causing it?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I've tried VonC's suggestions, but I'm still getting the same problem. I found these hs_err_pidxxxx.log files in my eclipse install directory. That log seems to suggest, it was caused by an OutOfMemoryError. I've already given 1G heap and 388M of permspace to eclipse, and at the time of the problem, it doesn't look like all memory was used. Can someone parse this log file for me, or point me to some place where i can find my answers? thanks!

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 161952 bytes for GrET in C:\BUILD_AREA\jdk6_18\hotspot\src\share\vm\utilities\growableArray.cpp. Out of swap space?
#
#  Internal Error (allocation.inline.hpp:39), pid=8948, tid=9376
#  Error: GrET in C:\BUILD_AREA\jdk6_18\hotspot\src\share\vm\utilities\growableArray.cpp
#
# JRE version: 6.0_18-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.0-b13 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x5cda0400):  VMThread [stack: 0x5ce30000,0x5cf30000] [id=9376]

Stack: [0x5ce30000,0x5cf30000],  sp=0x5cf2f98c,  free space=3fe5cf2f99ck
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f4000]
V  [jvm.dll+0xa1e0c]
V  [jvm.dll+0xcfe77]
V  [jvm.dll+0xc9f65]
V  [jvm.dll+0xce42a]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1d8592]
V  [jvm.dll+0xc9398]
V  [jvm.dll+0xc9791]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f44ad]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f6ed3]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f615e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f64ac]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1f68d2]
V  [jvm.dll+0x17f9cc]
C  [MSVCR71.dll+0x220b]
C  [kernel32.dll+0xb729]

VM_Operation (0x65edfbbc): GenCollectFull, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x60a2e400


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x6462dc00 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7000, stack(0x68ee0000,0x692e0000)]
  0x60b86400 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9872, stack(0x67b10000,0x67f10000)]
  0x60d54800 JavaThread "[ThreadPool Manager] - Idle Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8168, stack(0x5f120000,0x5f520000)]
  0x64622000 JavaThread "Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=2500, stack(0x66b10000,0x66f10000)]
  0x60a2e400 JavaThread "Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=4944, stack(0x65ae0000,0x65ee0000)]
  0x60b6ec00 JavaThread "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7744, stack(0x651e0000,0x655e0000)]
  0x5eec6800 JavaThread "Java indexing" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5932, stack(0x63c00000,0x64000000)]
  0x6078c400 JavaThread "Provisioning Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10220, stack(0x615e0000,0x619e0000)]
  0x608dd400 JavaThread "Worker-0" [_thread_blocked, id=4628, stack(0x601c0000,0x605c0000)]
  0x5e6eac00 JavaThread "Worker-JM" [_thread_blocked, id=4428, stack(0x611e0000,0x615e0000)]
  0x5e6dac00 JavaThread "[Timer] - Main Queue Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9544, stack(0x60de0000,0x611e0000)]
  0x60628000 JavaThread "Bundle File Closer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9680, stack(0x5fdc0000,0x601c0000)]
  0x5edaa400 JavaThread "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9248, stack(0x5f920000,0x5fd20000)]
  0x5eda6400 JavaThread "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8448, stack(0x5f520000,0x5f920000)]
  0x5e5ce000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9372, stack(0x5e7d0000,0x5ebd0000)]
  0x5cdc2400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=612, stack(0x5e130000,0x5e530000)]
  0x5cdbec00 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1900, stack(0x5cf30000,0x5d030000)]
  0x5cdb9c00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2444, stack(0x5dd30000,0x5e130000)]
  0x5cdb8400 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8368, stack(0x5d930000,0x5dd30000)]
  0x5cda4c00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9460, stack(0x5d530000,0x5d930000)]
  0x5cda3000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8472, stack(0x5d130000,0x5d530000)]
  0x008e6c00 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=9668, stack(0x00030000,0x00130000)]

Other Threads:
=>0x5cda0400 VMThread [stack: 0x5ce30000,0x5cf30000] [id=9376]
  0x5e5de400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x5ebd0000,0x5ecd0000] [id=8320]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x008e5d88] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x5cda0400
[0x008e6198] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x60a2e400

Heap
 def new generation   total 255296K, used 170678K [0x02a30000, 0x13f30000, 0x17f80000)
  eden space 226944K,  69% used [0x02a30000, 0x0c391190, 0x107d0000)
  from space 28352K,  48% used [0x12380000, 0x130cc7d8, 0x13f30000)
  to   space 28352K,   0% used [0x107d0000, 0x107d0000, 0x12380000)
 tenured generation   total 567180K, used 189005K [0x17f80000, 0x3a963000, 0x42a30000)
   the space 567180K,  33% used [0x17f80000, 0x238136b0, 0x23813800, 0x3a963000)
 compacting perm gen  total 131072K, used 59974K [0x42a30000, 0x4aa30000, 0x5aa30000)
   the space 131072K,  45% used [0x42a30000, 0x464c1990, 0x464c1a00, 0x4aa30000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x0040d000     C:\Program Files\Eclipse\helio\eclipse.exe
0x7c900000 - 0x7c9b2000     C:\WINNT\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000 - 0x7c8f6000     C:\WINNT\system32\kernel32.dll
0x7e410000 - 0x7e4a1000     C:\WINNT\system32\USER32.dll
0x77f10000 - 0x77f59000     C:\WINNT\system32\GDI32.dll
0x5d090000 - 0x5d12a000     C:\WINNT\system32\COMCTL32.dll
0x77dd0000 - 0x77e6b000     C:\WINNT\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e70000 - 0x77f03000     C:\WINNT\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77fe0000 - 0x77ff1000     C:\WINNT\system32\Secur32.dll
0x77c10000 - 0x77c68000     C:\WINNT\system32\MSVCRT.dll
0x76390000 - 0x763ad000     C:\WINNT\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x629c0000 - 0x629c9000     C:\WINNT\system32\LPK.DLL
0x74d90000 - 0x74dfb000     C:\WINNT\system32\USP10.dll
0x72000000 - 0x7200d000     C:\Program Files\Eclipse\helio\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.0.v20100503\eclipse_1307.dll
0x77c00000 - 0x77c08000     C:\WINNT\system32\VERSION.dll
0x74720000 - 0x7476c000     C:\WINNT\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x755c0000 - 0x755ee000     C:\WINNT\system32\msctfime.ime
0x774e0000 - 0x7761e000     C:\WINNT\system32\ole32.dll
0x6d8b0000 - 0x6db47000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76b40000 - 0x76b6d000     C:\WINNT\system32\WINMM.dll
0x7d000000 - 0x7d058000     C:\WINNT\system32\MSVCR71.dll
0x6d860000 - 0x6d86c000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x6d3e0000 - 0x6d3ff000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin\java.dll
0x6d340000 - 0x6d348000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin\hpi.dll
0x76bf0000 - 0x76bfb000     C:\WINNT\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d8a0000 - 0x6d8af000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x6d6c0000 - 0x6d6d3000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin\net.dll
0x71ab0000 - 0x71ac7000     C:\WINNT\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x71aa0000 - 0x71aa8000     C:\WINNT\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x71a50000 - 0x71a8f000     C:\WINNT\System32\mswsock.dll
0x76f20000 - 0x76f47000     C:\WINNT\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x76fb0000 - 0x76fb8000     C:\WINNT\System32\winrnr.dll
0x76f60000 - 0x76f8c000     C:\WINNT\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x76fc0000 - 0x76fc6000     C:\WINNT\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x6d610000 - 0x6d619000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin\management.dll
0x68000000 - 0x68036000     C:\WINNT\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x769c0000 - 0x76a74000     C:\WINNT\system32\USERENV.dll
0x5e770000 - 0x5e7c5000     C:\WINNT\system32\netapi32.dll
0x662b0000 - 0x66308000     C:\WINNT\system32\hnetcfg.dll
0x71a90000 - 0x71a98000     C:\WINNT\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x605d0000 - 0x605d9000     C:\WINNT\system32\mslbui.dll
0x6d6e0000 - 0x6d6e9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x619e0000 - 0x61a43000     C:\Program Files\Eclipse\helio\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\214\1\.cp\swt-win32-3650.dll
0x77120000 - 0x771ab000     C:\WINNT\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x763b0000 - 0x763f9000     C:\WINNT\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x773d0000 - 0x774d3000     C:\WINNT\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.6028_x-ww_61e65202\COMCTL32.dll
0x77f60000 - 0x77fd6000     C:\WINNT\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x61a50000 - 0x62267000     C:\WINNT\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x62270000 - 0x62356000     C:\WINNT\system32\WININET.dll
0x605c0000 - 0x605c9000     C:\WINNT\system32\Normaliz.dll
0x78130000 - 0x78263000     C:\WINNT\system32\urlmon.dll
0x62360000 - 0x62549000     C:\WINNT\system32\iertutil.dll
0x627b0000 - 0x627cd000     C:\Program Files\Eclipse\helio\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\214\1\.cp\swt-gdip-win32-3650.dll
0x62810000 - 0x629bb000     C:\WINNT\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.GdiPlus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.0.6001.22319_x-ww_f0b4c2df\gdiplus.dll
0x62ad0000 - 0x62ade000     C:\Program Files\Eclipse\helio\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\46\1\.cp\os\win32\x86\localfile_1_0_0.dll
0x62cd0000 - 0x62d08000     C:\WINNT\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x635e0000 - 0x6361a000     C:\WINNT\system32\oleacc.dll
0x63710000 - 0x639d5000     C:\WINNT\system32\xpsp2res.dll
0x76fd0000 - 0x7704f000     C:\WINNT\system32\CLBCATQ.DLL
0x77050000 - 0x77115000     C:\WINNT\system32\COMRes.dll
0x75cf0000 - 0x75d81000     C:\WINNT\system32\mlang.dll
0x76380000 - 0x76385000     C:\WINNT\system32\msimg32.dll
0x62c60000 - 0x62c6f000     C:\Program Files\Eclipse\helio\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\49\1\.cp\jWinHttp-1.0.0.dll
0x62d10000 - 0x62d69000     C:\WINNT\system32\WINHTTP.dll
0x76ee0000 - 0x76f1c000     C:\WINNT\system32\RASAPI32.DLL
0x76e90000 - 0x76ea2000     C:\WINNT\system32\rasman.dll
0x76eb0000 - 0x76edf000     C:\WINNT\system32\TAPI32.dll
0x76e80000 - 0x76e8e000     C:\WINNT\system32\rtutils.dll
0x62eb0000 - 0x62eb7000     C:\WINNT\system32\credssp.dll
0x77a80000 - 0x77b15000     C:\WINNT\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x77b20000 - 0x77b32000     C:\WINNT\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x767f0000 - 0x76818000     C:\WINNT\system32\schannel.dll
0x77c70000 - 0x77c94000     C:\WINNT\system32\msv1_0.dll
0x76d60000 - 0x76d79000     C:\WINNT\system32\iphlpapi.dll
0x634c0000 - 0x634c5000     C:\PROGRA~1\NETSUP~1\pcihooks.dll
0x68040000 - 0x68ad5000     C:\WINNT\system32\ieframe.dll
0x7e720000 - 0x7e7d0000     C:\WINNT\system32\SXS.DLL
0x7d1e0000 - 0x7d49c000     C:\WINNT\system32\msi.dll
0x77b40000 - 0x77b62000     C:\WINNT\system32\appHelp.dll
0x6a3a0000 - 0x6a953000     C:\WINNT\system32\mshtml.dll
0x67fc0000 - 0x67fe9000     C:\WINNT\system32\msls31.dll
0x746f0000 - 0x7471a000     C:\WINNT\system32\msimtf.dll
0x63b50000 - 0x63b90000     C:\WINNT\ime\sptip.dll
0x63b90000 - 0x63ba1000     C:\WINNT\IME\SPGRMR.DLL
0x63b30000 - 0x63b3c000     C:\WINNT\system32\ImgUtil.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -Xss4m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m -XX:CompileThreshold=5 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=c:\jintegra\lib\jintegra.jar
PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_18/bin/../jre/lib/i386;C:\Oracle\product\10.2.0.1.0\Client_1\bin;C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\;C:\Program Files\Support Tools\;C:\Perl\bin\;C:\WINNT\system32;C:\WINNT;C:\WINNT\System32\Wbem;c:\jintegra\bin;C:\WINNT\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Sysinternals\Bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\
USERNAME=rfang
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 3

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 3108388k(295496k free), swap 5043676k(1054940k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.0-b13) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_18-b07), built on Dec 17 2009 13:35:55 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Thu Feb 10 15:00:24 2011
elapsed time: 936 seconds
```

Comment: Try first to change your `eclipse.ini` and see if it makes any difference with those large project builds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by adding -XXMaxPermSize=128M. Apparently the eclipse-specific --launcher.MaxPermSize override did not take effect although according to Eclipse support it should have.